# CSS styling a link but not ::before content

Tags: html, css

Challenge: I would like to apply css styling 'underlined' to a link when hovered, but not to the content given by the css ::before selector. The goal is to underline the link text only, but not the ::before prefix when hovered.

It seems that the last styling line does not work:
`.fontIcon a:hover::before { text-decoration: none; }`
but when I specify e.g. some coloring, this does work.

Thanks for your hints.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fontIcon {
  font-family: 'Arial', bold;
}

.fontIcon:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.fontIcon a::before {
  content: "- ";
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fontIcon a:hover::before {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Challenge</h1>
<span class="fontIcon">
        <a id="thelink" href="#">
    The Dash-Prefix should not be underlined when hovered
    </a>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
a                   { text-decoration: none; }
.fontIcon           { font-family: 'Arial', bold; }
.fontIcon:hover     { text-decoration: underline; }
.fontIcon a::before { content: "- "; text-decoration: none; }
.fontIcon:hover a:before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 4px; /* optional */
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Challenge</h1>
    <span class="fontIcon">
        <a id="thelink" href="#">The Dash-Prefix should not be underlined when hovered</a>
    </span>
  <body>
</html>
```

Comment: i understand you only made the :hover + :before element an inline-block and added the padding-right. This is really minimal invasive - thanks for your hint

Answer (score 0):

For people who do not want to solve by creating a pseudo-element, here is a solution for you:

https://codepen.io/louielyl/pen/YzeOYea

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <ul>
      <a class="link" href="https://codepen.io/louielyl/pen/YzeOYea">
        <li>Hover me and you will see the underline.</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
.link{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.link:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```